# How to include a venv folder in the gitignore

Tags: unity-game-engine, github, gitignore

I have a venv -python virtual environment- folder within my unity project, and to backup my project i commit and push to github. But after including this venv file within the project itself. The venv contains files that are too large to be pushed to github, would it be possible to add the venv file to the gitignore and if so how? Or is this not a good idea... I am relatively inexperienced with github so any help would be appreciated.

[Written ( '/venv/' in the gitignore file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5At5.png)
I have tried writing '/venv/' in the gitignore, and it has removed some of the files from being picked up by git but not all of them.
[The message i am getting from git desktop saying the files are too large for pushing to github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdcfD.png)
this is the message i am getting from the github desktop app. suggesting using git LFS, but i don't want to use this as the project is already on github.

Comment: how big is big ? LFS?

Comment: You can still migrate an already existing project into LFS afterwards ..

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few options for adding large /venv/ files to Git!

Git LFS can be implemented for existing projects to store files up to 5GB on the repository. I've had success using it with projects already on Github. Instructions for doing so are here: https://git-lfs.com/

Alternatively, you could use a requirements.txt file. This will take note of everything in your virtual environment and allow users to quickly and easily install everything they need. It may eliminate the need to store /venv/ remotely. For more info, see here: https://frankcorso.dev/setting-up-python-environment-venv-requirements.html

It boils down to this:

1. Run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` while in the virtual environment to make a list of all your pips
2. To install the requirements, run: `pip install -r requirements.txt` while inside a virtual environment